# executing a java class file from ant script

Tags: java, ant, junit4

I need to run a java class (actually a test case) from ant script. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: It is very common scenario, have a look at http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/ant/UsingAnttoexecuteclassfile.shtml

Comment: what class you want to run? There are many tasks already.. You can add a custom task too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the most basic level you could use the ant [`java`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task to do this.

But you tagged with junit4 - can you not use the ant [`junit`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task?

Answer (score 1):

To execute java class, you can use java task http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

To execute junit test cases: http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html#testing

Answer (score 1):

Try the [java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task. If you want to run tests, you might want to take a look at JUnit