# How to make build.xml file to run a program?

Tags: java, ant

Two questions.

1. How do I make a build.xml file run a Java program?  What are the commands?
2. Is there a way to run a Java program through Ant , without creating the .class files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [executing a java class file from ant script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984781/executing-a-java-class-file-from-ant-script)

Answer (score 2):

1- You can use a [java command](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) to run java program and create a custom task like:

```
<target name="run">
  <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

2- I think no, you need to comile your code before execute it, and it's not a big problem, if you use ANT. Just make a task to do that like:

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>
```

And then you can execute a main method of custom java class, like:

```
<java classname="com.example.MainClass" depends="compile">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="build/classes"/>
    </classpath>
</java>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look here for a basic tutorial on Ant: https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

As far as I know, it is impossible to run a Java program without creating .class files, as the JVM interprets .class files rather than .java files.

I think you have misunderstood the purpose of Ant. It builds Java applications, and part of this build involves compiling the .java files into .class files for you. Typically this would be so that you can deploy applications onto a server more easily.

To compile .java files using Ant, use the `javac` command, as in the tutorial:

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>
```